# How can I change the useragent and referer for javascript in IWebBrowser2 in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, user-agent, iwebbrowser2, referer

I wrote a simple C++ program that opens a test page in IE window using IWebBrowser2 with my HTML header (Referer, UserAgent). Everything works fine. PHP functions on the test page show the modified headers. However, Javascript (document.referrer, navigator.userAgent) does not. How to set referer and useragent for Javascript in IWebBrowser2 IE window?

This is my program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Exdisp.h>

int main(){
    if (SUCCEEDED(OleInitialize(NULL))){
        IWebBrowser2* wb;

        CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&wb);

        if(wb){
            VARIANT vempty;
            VariantInit(&vempty);

            VARIANT vheaders = { 0 };
            BSTR headers = SysAllocString( L"Referer: http://example.com\r\nUser-Agent: xyz\r\n" );
            V_VT( &vheaders ) = VT_BSTR;
            V_BSTR( &vheaders ) = headers;

            BSTR url = SysAllocString(L"http://localhost/test2.php");

            HRESULT hr = wb->Navigate(url, &vempty, &vempty, &vempty, &vheaders);

            if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
                wb->put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE);
            }
            else{
               wb->Quit();
            }

            SysFreeString(url);
            SysFreeString(headers);
            wb->Release();
        }

        OleUninitialize();
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `navigator.userAgent`?

Comment: navigator.userAgent has the value: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko. And document.referrer is empty.

Comment: That looks very much like an `Internet Explorer` User-Agent string. Are you _sure_ you're allowed to pass in headers?

Comment: Yes, the headers are sent, because PHP variables $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] and $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] on the test page show the changed values​​. Only javascript functions still shows the "old" value.

Comment: Oh, well that makes sense of course. The headers you're setting are just for the request. You're not actually giving the browser instructions to report a different user-agent. I'm not sure how you would go about doing that.

Comment: May be you can do it from inside the javascript code. Can you try the first sample code from [this page](http://www.icenium.com/resources/forums/html5-css-javascript-/is-it-possible-to-change-the-useragent-)

Comment: @MohamedA. I don't have the possibility of applying it. I need to set the navigator.userAgent and document.referrer for IE windows launched by IWebBrowsert2.

Comment: From what I've found it's possible to change it, by overriding the OnAmbientProperty of the IWebControl2, [this guy here did it](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?379812-IWebBrowser2-User-Agent-String) . But according to [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/08/extending-the-user-agent-string-problems-and-alternatives.aspx)  the javascript code won't see the change (from the article : _However, the overridden property is not used when programmatically calling the Navigate method, and it will not impact the userAgent property of the DOM's navigator ..._) .

Comment: @MohamedA. You're right, javascript code won't see this change. Maybe work override settings DOM's property, but how to do it in IWebBrowser2 (IE Window)?

Comment: +1 for showing what you have tried.